# efficiently coding Switch function in R where many arguments may map to one

Tags: r, switch-statement

I'm wondering how I would efficiently code using the switch function (but open to other methods) in the following situation.

I have many possible inputs to my switch function that map to the same thing. For example,

```
switch("purple", "purple" = "color", 
                 "blue" = "color", 
                 "orange" = "color", 
                 "square" = "shape")
```

What I'd like to do is not having to write separate lines for the colors. So something like this,

```
switch("purple", c("purple","blue","orange") = "color",  
                 "square" = "shape")
```

The context is that I'm using a switch function in a shiny app in order to subset a data frame according to the user input. For most of the possible inputs, it's a straight forward subset of the data set, as in.

```
user's choice = data[data$choice_column %in% user's choice, ]
```

but then I would have to write this for each of these choices, which can be handful.

I'm obviously open to other methods as well.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure I get this. The user interface lets the user choose a column and some values from that column and you want to select the rows in `data` that have those choices? Then somehow you've decided you need a `select` function?

Comment: @Spacedman: I realized I didn't explain why I'm using switch fully. right, the user chooses one or multiple checkboxes which are values of one column in the data table. The reason I'm using switch is that I want to included "All" and "All x kind" (a subset of more than one row) as options for which switch is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `switch` allows for multiple arguments mapped to the same answer. Simply add the arguments with no answers, up to an argument which has an answer. In this example, "purple", "blue" and "orange" are all mapped to "color":

`switch("purple", "purple" = , 
                 "blue" = , 
                 "orange" = "color", 
                 "square" = "shape",
                 "the last value is the default answer")
[1] "color"`

Comment: thank you! The trick in my case using this was learning that the first argument has to be a string, where as my reactive input was a vector of strings (when more than one option is chosen in the checkboxes). easy fix using paste(, collapse=" ").

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
x <- "purple"
obj <- c("colour", "colour", "colour", "shape")
names(obj) <- c("purple","blue","orange", "square")
obj[x]
```

Comment: the elements of obj would be reactives in my case but this idea may work with lists. Let me think on it more...